# How delete one item in firebase by key I am try some thing like this but not work with me

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my code to delete one item in firebase in child recipe the method deletes all the list item in the recipe on click one item I think that because for loop the get all item not specific item and delete all of them I don't know how can delete just one item in the list key I went delete the one key just one on click button delete
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xks5.jpg)

the recipe reference has two keys when click delete button delete all key not one

```
 holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getRootView().getContext());
            builder1.setTitle("Delete post");
            builder1.setMessage("Are you sure that you want delete the post?");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {

                            ref.child("recipe").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for(DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                        String skey = uniqueKeySnapshot.getKey();
                                        uniqueKeySnapshot.child(String.valueOf(id)).child(skey).getRef().removeValue();                           //ref.child("recipe").child(skey).setValue(null);
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "error !"+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });



                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    "No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
        }

    });
```

i make for loop in chiled bacuse have list recipe

Comment: post the code not image. Also not getting what you actually want.if you want to delete anything inside POST first u need to get the key. Key you can get by searching with any unique variable like postID.  get key(ajskshsksj something like this) from post id then like this DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("POst").child(key you get);
                dR.removeValue();

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this

```
reference2.child(YOUR_ITEM_KEY).setValue(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no removing code line in your screenshot.

```
reference2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       dataSnapshot.getRef.removeValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //for database error
    }
});
```

Or simply,

`reference2.removeValue();`

Don't post your code as image in the next time.